# combine all columns in Dataframe (pandas) - python3

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to combine all data from all columns into one column. Like this:

```
A B C                X
1 2 3               123
3 2 1      -->      321 
5 6 7               567
```

Bearing in mind that we don't know the number of columns and rows.

I tried to solve it like this, but It doesn't work.

```
db.assign(sum = db.apply(''.join, axis = 1)).drop([db.index], axis = 1)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work?

```
df.astype(str).sum(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Given:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,3,5],'B':[2,2,6],'C':[3,1,7]})
```

Results:

```
   A  B  C    X
0  1  2  3  123
1  3  2  1  321
2  5  6  7  567
```

Comment: Cool one (already upvoted) but string concatenation is slow, this builds a new string for each concatenation. May not be efficient for large dfs

Comment: @Chester I agree!  There are more efficient ways.

Comment: `df.astype(str).agg(''.join, axis=1)` might be faster, sum performs pairwise concatenation (since strings are immutable).

Answer (score 3):

We can use [`np.geomspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.geomspace.html#numpy.geomspace) with `df.mul` then `df.sum`

```
c = df.shape[1]
end = 10**(c-1)
df['X'] = df.mul(np.geomspace(end, 1, num=c)).sum(1)

   A  B  C      X
0  1  2  3  123.0
1  3  2  1  321.0
2  5  6  7  567.0
```

Timeit analysis:

Benchmarking setup:

```
vals = np.random.randint(2, 10, (100_000, 6))
df = pd.DataFrame(vals)
```

---

```
In [93]: %%timeit
    ...: df.astype(str).sum(axis=1).astype(int)
    ...: 
    ...: 
419 ms ± 3.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [94]: %%timeit
    ...: c = df.shape[1]
    ...: end = 10**(c-1)
    ...: df.mul(np.geomspace(end, 1, num=c)).sum(1)
    ...: 
    ...: 
8.02 ms ± 170 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Using arithmetic here is very elegant, good work!

Comment: This is a very nicely thought out trick!